# How can I call a php file with an event on Windows machine?

Tags: php, cron

Assume that we have a device which sends data (a file) back to the computer whenever something unexpected happens. Let's say if it detects a movement, it will send a data file to the computer.

The computer should notice and parse this file. Afterwards, it should execute a PHP file to do other stuff.

Currently we are using scheduled tasks on windows, but this checks the status minimum every 1 minute. Is there any way to detect this as soon as we received this? What can be used?

EDIT: In other words, how can I set a trigger to execute the php?

EDIT: there was a typo. I wrote pdf instead of php.

Comment: how does the device send the data

Comment: @meda the device is sending the file using serial port.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is write a simple Windows Service, which will parse the file once received.

look into [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to detect the file. this way you don't need to schedule any task.

Now as for the PHP script you should be able to start a  command line process and execute the php.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into http://gruntjs.com/ and use it as a listener for changes on a directory. This could be used to trigger a PHP script.